# Why is rails 3.1 wrapping part of my params hash, but not all of it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying out some simple stuff with rails and google maps.  I have a marker model with a few attributes: latitude, longitude, and icon. My app is POSTing json to a standard REST markers controller. Watching from my browser, the json looks like this:

```
{"latitude":40.666700768608465,"longitude":-99.722078125,"icon":"http://localhost:3000/assets/4.png","id":"C4150EEB-D861-4B36-B69B-154C567F51CB"}
```

(That id is generated by a javascript MVC on the front end)

In the logs it looks like this:

```
Started POST "/markers" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-12 23:41:25 -0700 
Processing by MarkersController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"latitude"=>40.666700768608465, "longitude"=>-99.722078125, "icon"=>"http://localhost:3000/assets/4.png", "id"=>"C4150EEB-D861-4B36-B69B-154C567F51CB", "marker"=>{"id"=>"C4150EEB-D861-4B36-B69B-154C567F51CB", "icon"=>"http://localhost:3000/assets/4.png"}}
```

In my controller, `params[:marker]` has an icon and id (which is ignored in create/update), but not the longitude and latitude.  Why would it put some attributes in and leave other attributes out?  I have them all `attr_accessible`.

Answer (score 1):

Your form or your JavaScript is wrong. The coordinates are in `params[:latitude]` and `params[:longitude]` rather than inside `params[:marker]`. You'll also notice that `params[:icon]` and `params[:id]` are the same as `params[:marker][:icon]` and `params[:marker][:id]` so it looks like your client-side code is rather confused.

Comment: What json should my client-side javascript be sending? It looks fine to me. I don't understand why rails is putting it into the params hash arbitrarily.

Comment: @phaedryx: I don't think Rails is the problem, looks like the client-side code is confused. The JSON should be something like this: `{"marker": {"latitude": 40.666700768608465, "longitude": -99.722078125, "icon": "http://localhost:3000/assets/4.png", "id": "C4150EEB-D861-4B36-B69B-154C567F51CB"}}`. How is the data built in your JavaScript?